# Импортировать данные в SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

1. Есть БД в MySQL. Можно ли ее как-то импортировать в SQLite?
2. Есть файл в котором каждая строка разделена на две части например Слово$Перевод. Первая часть до $ одна колонка как бы вторая часть после $ вторая колонка. Можно ли из нее как-то загрузить данные в SQLite?
3. Есть таблица в Excel Можно ли из нее данные импортировать в SQLite?

Вообще как быстро из какой-то БД загрузить данные в SQLite? или может сразу сохранить в виде SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь перечень инструментов для конвертации

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

Для Excel и csv есть ресурс

http://converttosqlite.com/convert/
но я  лично не пробовал

Также в администраторе SQlite Studio есть возможность импорта csv (Вы для управления базой какой-нибудь администратор скорее всего поставите и там, возможно также есть меню "Import")